# Lotus Notes Domino Redirect

Tags: json, redirect, lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-domino

I am trying to pass credentials via AJAX to a Domino Database to have it automatically login and return Data in JSON.

Domino seems  to chop off everthing after the "?ReadViewEntries"

http://www.Server.com/daterbase.nsfopen&login&username=USERNAME&password=THEPASSWORD&RedirectTo=daterbase.nsf/JSONBookView?ReadViewEntries&count=500&RestrictToCategory=MYCATEGORY&outputformat=json";

Thanks in Advance!
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RedirectTo query string argument needs to be URL Encoded so that the server sees the "&count=500..." as part of the RedirectTo value rather than as query string arguments to the original page.

For example, use:

> http://www.Server.com/daterbase.nsfopen&login&username=USERNAME&password=THEPASSWORD&RedirectTo=daterbase.nsf/JSONBookView?daterbase.nsf%2FJSONBookView%3FReadViewEntries%26count%3D500%26RestrictToCategory%3DMYCATEGORY%26outputformat%3Djson%22