# How to pass parameters to an agent with authentication

Tags: lotus-notes

I've got a web agent which accepts a couple parameters which it uses to do a lookup and return file.  But I need to authenticate first.

If I do this:

```
http://url.com/agentName?openagent&p1=test1&p2=test2
```

the agent works fine and returns the file.

But when I try to add the authentication piece:

```
http://url.com/names.nsf?username=test&password=test&redirectto=http://url.com/agentName?openagent&p1=test1&p2=test2
```

the agent sees only "openagent"in query_string_decoded(0) field.   The rest of the parameters are lost.

Is there a way to do this?

thanks
clem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try URLEncoding the redirectto parameter.

```
http://url.com/names.nsf?username=test&password=test&redirectto=http%3A%2F%2Furl.com%2FagentName%3Fopenagent%26p1%3Dtest1%26p2%3Dtest2
```

Comment: interesting idea!  But, it didn't work.  Same result.

Comment: This answer suggests it should have worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805878/lotus-notes-domino-redirect

Comment: It did work!  I checked my url and found that I had not replaced the dots (.).  Ended up having to write a little tool to help do the replacement.  Thanks!